# The existence of anti-derivatives

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, exponential-function

[image]

The only thing I can think of is that the function is continuous hence the anti derivative exists. I was wondering if there is anything else that needs to be done/said?

Comment: Maybe you can explain how you know it's continuous. Otherwise this seems enough.

Comment: Does the explanation involve saying that the composition of continuous functions is continuous (as we have that exponential is continuous and z^2 is continuous)?

Answer (score 2):

Your idea "the function is continuous hence the anti-derivative exits" doesn't work. This is true for *real* functions, but it is not true anymore in the complex case.

For example, complex conjugation $z\mapsto \bar z$ is continuous, but is not the derivative of anything (on any nonempty open set).

---

*After* a course in complex analysis, the argument that $z\mapsto e^{z^2}$ is a derivative would be as easy as

> $z\mapsto e^{z^2}$ is differentiable everywhere by the chain rule. Therefore it has an antiderivative everywhere.

But if you don't yet know that a differentiable function on a simply connected domain always has an antiderivative, you may need to do more than that. *What* you need to do depends on what you *do* know so far, though.